# How do you achieve a retro 3D style, today?

Tags: rendering

Limitations of 90's 3d computer graphics produced some very stylized images.

See here: https://www.pcmag.com/news/trippy-3d-art-from-the-early-90s

I can't quite articulate, in 3d terms, why it looks retro. Low resolution? Harsh shadows? Lighting? Unrealistic materials? Of course, today's technology has gotten a lot better and more realistic.

What techniques would you use to create a 90's 3d retro style today?

I'm a beginner in 3d software. Thanks!

[image: Robert A. Mickelsen]
Robert A. Mickelsen

Answer (score 2):

This is a brilliant question. One of the main things was that back then, everything was in grayspace. There was very little in the way of raytracing, so non-lamped areas, reflected (or absorbed) a particularly dead gray. This is apparent even in the most well produced 3D animation and art of the time.

Because processing power was so low, edges weren't beveled, so they were infinitely sharp--a real reality breaker.

Textures were often applied directly to primitive faces so the scale and vanishing points rarely matched between different textures if applied to planes. This gives a kind of "collage" effect that is, besides the gray cast, a hallmark of 90s 3D art.

Also, lighting was really cold, and because of the gray-ness of the surrounding bodies, everything had a gray cast.

I hope this addresses some of the issues in play, though not all of them, I'm sure.

Comment: Does a _"brilliant question"_ not warrant an upvote?